# Performance of Eigen library in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, eigen, eigen3

I've integrated eigen into a project which Xcode compiles to simulator -- the code works however runs very slowly. Code which uses the Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver to compute eigendecompisiton of a covariance matrix executes in around 10 minutes on a linux machine -- but takes 2 hours to complete in the iOS simulator running on a mac pro with equivalent xeon processor ... Has anyone seen something like this before and have advice on how to debug?

I'm assuming that somehow the compiler options used for the simulator target are confusing eigen and causing it not to take advantage of the x86_64 vector hardware...  But I'm not sure what compiler options might be the cause.

My goal is to speedup execution of code that is compiled for iOS simulator -- the majority of this code targets iOS but we are running some related code from the project (which involves eigen) in the iOS playground context for rapid iteration ...

Comment: Have you set the build configuration of the "Run" scheme to release (or enabled compiler optimisations for debug builds)?

Comment: That seems quite unexpected.  You should profile your code in Instruments to see what is taking up the extra time and file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com with your results.

Comment: I haven't yet deployed this code to a iOS app target so I can use the profiling tools -- I've only executed the code from playground so far which doesn't have any analysis tools ...  The code relies on access to a large dataset stored in ~/Documents/Shared Playground Data and as far as I know there's no way to get this data into an app target without copying.  I discovered recently that I can hack the simulator sandbox with a symlink -- although I have to manually recreate the symlink every application launch - will try this and see if I can learn anything from profiling tools

Comment: 10mn to run `SelfAdjointEigenSolver` on a Linux workstation, either your problem is huge (around 10000^2 ?), or you definitely forgot to enable compiler optimizations (e.g., -O3).

Comment: Are you asking after problem size as a function of number of elements in the matrix?  10000^2 elements in the matrix sounds about right -- input matrices are between 7 and 15k rows with somewhere around 16384 columns ...